# How many African countries currently deploy Cat 3 ILS?

Tags: ils

How many countries in Africa currently operate Cat 3 ILS?

Comment: I think this will answer your question:https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71602/is-there-a-list-of-airports-with-category-3-ils-systems

Comment: What have you searched for so far?  It seems that this might be relatively simple to find online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of airports with Category 3 ILS systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71602/is-there-a-list-of-airports-with-category-3-ils-systems)

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71602/is-there-a-list-of-airports-with-category-3-ils-systems) has a list of all airports with a Cat III ILS system.

Africa was assigned ICAO region codes D, F, G and H, so you can just look for ICAO airport codes on the list starting with those letters. The only one I see is "GMMN (MOHAMMED V INTL) on runways: 35L, 35R". That name wan't familiar to me, but a quick Google search says that GMMN is Casablanca, Morocco.