# Is there any latest List of CAT IIIB airports in the world?

Tags: ils

Recently I had my very first CATIIIB experience at my own homebase (VILK) and since then I've been keen to know more about this most advanced landing system we have in the aviation as of now and given its such a costly instrument and its maintenance is no easy feat I was wondering how many airports around the world may have this technology..does anyone have any data ?

Thank you

Comment: Related: [Is there a list of airports with Category 3 ILS systems?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71602/is-there-a-list-of-airports-with-category-3-ils-systems)

Comment: Thanks for that Mr Bianfable..but this list seems to be outdated now.

Comment: @Avgeeker That list was from Dec 2019, and it’s unlikely to have changed much in 15 months.

Comment: It doesn't have BLR The latest airport to be equipped with CATIIIB ILS and I was looking for the list of CATIIIB airports specifically I know the number of CATIIIB airports is far less than CATIIIA like Canada doesn't have a single CATIIIB runway ..so I'm looking to make a list of only CATIIIB airports for my research.

Comment: Prishtina Internationell Airport have Cat III B